# Plotting a function in React with dynamic input

Tags: reactjs, function, plot, charts

I'm working on my first project in React and I'm kind of stuck. I've been able to make a chart work with this library: https://mauriciopoppe.github.io/function-plot/

My code looks like this:

```
import './App.css';
import functionPlot from "function-plot";

functionPlot({
    target: '#test',
    width: 580,
    height: 400,
    yAxis: {
      label: 'y axis',
      domain: [0, 40]
    },
    xAxis: {
        label: 'x axis',
        domain: [0, 30]
    },
    data: [{
      fn: '0.01x^2 + 15'
    }],
    disableZoom: true,
    grid: true
  })

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div id="test"></div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

[And this is what it looks like so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s5jym.png)

Now I would like to add two input fields and a submit button to update the chart dynamicaly. The formula is "ax^2 + b" and I would like the parameters a and b to come from the input fields from the user.

Maybe this is not the best way of doing it, if so please give me tips. All tips and tricks are appreciated, thanks :)

---

Here is the code that worked for me:

```
import './App.css';
import functionPlot from "function-plot";
import React, { Component, setState } from 'react'

class App extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      a: '',
      b: ''
    };

    this.handleChangeA = this.handleChangeA.bind(this);
    this.handleChangeB = this.handleChangeB.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleChangeA(event) {
    this.setState({
      a: event.target.value
    });
  }

  handleChangeB(event) {
    this.setState({
      b: event.target.value
    });
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    alert('A ' + this.state.a + ' B ' + this.state.b);
    event.preventDefault();
    functionPlot({
      target: '#test',
      width: 580,
      height: 400,
      yAxis: {
        label: 'Y axis',
        domain: [0, 40]
      },
      xAxis: {
          label: 'X axis',
          domain: [0, 30]
      },
      data: [{
        fn: `${this.state.a}x^2 + ${this.state.b}`
      }],
      disableZoom: true,
      grid: true
    })
  }

 
  render() {
    return (
 
      <div className="App">
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <label>
            Verdi A:
            <input type="text" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChangeA} />
          </label>
          <label>
            Verdi B:
            <input type="text" value={this.state.b} onChange={this.handleChangeB} />
          </label>
          <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
      <div id="test"></div>
     </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

This is what it looks like:
[image]

If anyone have some constructive criticism I'm all ears :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "good" way to do, is to store `a` and `b` in the state of your component App. Then in the App component, you display 2 input field, which are updating the state `a` and `b`. Then you render your chart, by calling your function `functionPlot` (in the return function of the App component), by giving the object that you already have, but you replace your static `a` and `b` value with your state :

```
fn: `${a}x^2 + ${b}`
```

Is it clear enough ?

Comment: Thanks, man I appreciate it :) I made it work with this code:

Comment: Oh great! If my answer is usefull, you can accept it, by clicking on the accept button!